# Placing text on a PNG image iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So i have an app which needs some text based data in the image like a calendar app in which shows a calendar and Some User input text that a user has entered and it would appear in the image. I know its an NSString or some sort but what i don't yet understand is how do i implement this. Here is an example:

[image: User Text]

As you may see in this calendar app, the user set up a reminder in which displays data, what i want to do is place additional data like in the image itself also.

Another thing is how would i add this kind of image to an app which should show a UITableView right below the image?

Any great tutorials on how to accomplish this ? The image should be editable meaning it can be deleted like an icon on an iPhone where if i click edit, it would show a Delete icon.

Answer (score 0):

To add text to the image you can use this method:

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image withText:(NSString *)text ofFont:(UIFont *)font inFrame:(CGRect)textFrame {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.0f);

    NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{
        NSFontAttributeName: font
    };

    [text drawInRect:textFrame withAttributes:textAttributes];

    UIImage* imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageWithText;
}
```

Usage example:

```
// Get some image from somewhere
UIImage *someImage = ...;

// The text that will be shown on the image
NSString *text = @"Some text"; 

// Font of text
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:17.0]; 

// Location of text
CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20); 

// Get result image with text
UIImage *someImageWithText = [self image:someImage withText:text ofFont:font inFrame:textFrame];

// Show result image within UIImageView
_imageView.image = someImageWithText;
```